# load model spacy error: ExtraData: unpack(b) received extra data

Tags: load, spacy, msgpack

I have trained a custom NER model in spacy(v3.4.2) and then I trained the Roberta base model for custom NER again with spacy(v3.4.4) transformers.

Now I am trying to load the Roberta trained model in spacy(v3.4.2) in order to combine NERs and I am facing this error:

[image]

Can anybody help? Maybe it is happening because of different versions?

Comment: Please post your error as text. I'm not entirely sure what's going on in your error - it's hard to read - but you usually can't take something trained in a new version back to an old version. Can you try using the same version?